# Check for valid 2D array size for 'Max-Out' game

Tags: java, arrays, error-handling

I have this max out game board set up. its a 6 by 6 matrix using arrays made up of user input. the user enters 36 numbers separated by a space, and the matrix is built up. I need to check to make sure the arrays are each 6 ints long. I am able to confirm when they are by using board.length, but when I intentionally enter too many, it just seems to ignore the extra, and if I enter too little, I get really weird output.

Some of the code was prewritten by my professor so I am not entirely familiar with the inner workings.

I got it to print out the total ints (36) by adding up the lengths, but it still gives me 'correct' sizes when I enter too many ints. I am guessing its because my loop stops at 6, so perhaps it just ignores the extras. I tried to have it print "big stuff" if there are too many ints, but it doesnt happen.

Here is the main part, i believe it has all the relevant code

```
public class MaxOut {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int ROWS = 6;
        final int COLS = 6;

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the matrix (36 numbers)");
        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            int[][] board = new int[ROWS][COLS];
            for (int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++)
                for (int c = 0; c < COLS; c++)
                    board[r][c] = s.nextInt();
            if((board[0].length + board[1].length+ board[2].length+ board[3].length+ board[4].length+ board[5].length)>36){
                System.out.println("big stuff");
            }else {
                System.out.println((board[0].length + board[1].length+ board[2].length+ board[3].length+ board[4].length+ board[5].length));
            }

            int boardTotal = 0;
            for (int r = 0; r < 6; r++)
                for (int c = 0; c < 6; c++)
                    boardTotal += board[r][c];
            System.out.println("The sum of each number in the matrix is " + boardTotal);
            for (int[] row : board)
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));

            boolean[][] covered = new boolean[6][6];
            System.out.println("The maximum score for this board is " + maxVal(board, covered, 0, 0));
        }
        s.close();
    }
```

I would like for it to check for the size, so that the user has to enter 36 ints to make the board.

Currently, it just ignores extra ints, or it gives me a lot of dashes and exes(another method) when I enter too few.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has three loops:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {  // 1st loop
        int[][] board = new int[ROWS][COLS];
        for (int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++)  // 2nd loop
            for (int c = 0; c < COLS; c++)  // 3rd loop
                board[r][c] = s.nextInt();
```

which means that 6 times you are creating and populating a 6x6 matrix.

Comment: I moved  int[][] board = new int[ROWS][COLS]; to outside of the main first loop now. I still am unsure about checking that the user enters the right amount of ints

Comment: the problem remains - you still have **three** loops, meaning you're doing 6x6x6 processing. you need to remove one loop.